# How GAMG Preconditioner in OpenFOAM really works?

Tags: simulation, fluid-dynamics

I use OpenFOAM for CFD simulations. A very popular preconditioner is [GAMG](http://www.openfoam.com/features/linear-solvers.php) which needs a low number of iterations per a time step in SIMPLE or PISO solvers that are used to simulate the fluid flow.

I would like to understand how GAMG prepares the internal structures.

Does it create the internal data structures used in GAMG **only once** in a single iteration on the basis of the geometry and then the entries in these data structures are only updated?

OR

Does it create the interal data structures multiple times in a single iteration? 
I read the documentation [here](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~hani/kurser/OS_CFD_2008/TimBehrens/tibeh-report-fin.pdf) but it does not have the answer.

Thanks for your answer.